How to use dot and square bracket notation as a string key to access a nested dictionary/list structure
Let's say I have a nested dictionary that looks something like this:
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": {
        "e": 4,
        "f": 5
    },
    "g": [{
        "h": 6,
        "i": 7
    },
    {
        "h": 8,
        "i": 9
    }]
}

However, I have been provided with a string key in dot notation form. If the key is, for example, key = "d.e", how can I use this to get the value 4 from the above dictionary? Similarly, for a nested object which is an array of dicts, I would like to do the same to access g[0].h and g[1].h.
I do not want to convert the dictionary as in How to use a dot "." to access members of dictionary?, I want to preserve the use of the string as the key to access the objects.
I have tried using the reduce function as in Checking a nested dictionary using a dot notation string "a.b.c.d.e", automatically create missing levels by OP or Nested dictionary value from key path, but it does not handle nested arrays.

I'd create a custom MyDict child class of dict where __getitem__(self, k) is k1, k_other = str(k).split('.', 1); if k_other: return self[k][k_other]; else: return super().__getitem__(k1) ;
No time to test it though so not sure it will work out of the box

The techniques in those duplicates can be used, you just need to parse [index] in addition to .key. So you can't just use split('.'), you need a more complete parser.

@Barmar Yeah I have posted an answer to that effect

The code below works with the following assumptions:

Dictionary keys are always separated by dots .
Keys provided in brackets [] are always integers. This is true
for all kinds of sequences (lists, tuples, even substrings of strings), but doesn't work with ranges (e.g. [:1]) or multidimensional arrays (e.g. [1, 2]).

import re

my_dct = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": {"e": 4, "f": 5 }, "g": [{"h": 6, "i": 7 }, {"h": 8, "i": 9}]}

def get(key: str, dct: dict):
    key_parts = []  # Assemble a list of keys, no matter whether for dicts or sequences
    for part in key.split("."):  # Split at the dictionary level
        if matched := re.match(r"(.*?)(?:\[(?:[+-]?\d+)\])+", part):  # Split at the list level if necessary
            key_parts.append(matched.group(1))
            for subpart in re.findall(r"\[([+-]?\d+)\]", part):  # Append list indices
                key_parts.append(int(subpart))
        else:
            key_parts.append(part)
    result = dct
    while key_parts:  # Consume assembled list of keys
        result = result[key_parts.pop(0)]
    return result
   
print(get("g[0].h", my_dct))  # >>> 6
print(get("a[0][+0][-1].x", {"a":[[[{"x": 1}]]]}))  # >>> 1


You can iterate over the key path by matching key access (a/.a) or index access ([0]) and then cutting it off for the next iteration.
def find(struct, path, default=None):
    while path != "":
        # if key and dict structure
        if (m := re.match(r"^\.?([^\.\[]+)", path)) and isinstance(struct, dict):
            key = m[1]
        # if index and list structure
        elif (m := re.match(r"^\[(\d+)\]", path)) and isinstance(struct, (list, tuple)):
            key = int(m[1])
        # else invalid and return the default
        else:
            return default

        # if key/index doesn't exit return the default
        try:
            struct = struct[key]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            return default

        # cut current path off for next iteration
        path = path[len(m[0]):]

    return struct

For invalid paths, it returns the default value.
struct = {
    "d": {
        "e": 4,
        "f": 5
    },
    "g": [
        {
            "h": 6,
            "i": 7
        },
        {
            "h": 8,
            "i": 9
        },
    ],
    "a": [
        (1, 2),
        (3, 4),
    ],
}
for path in  [
    "d.e",
    "g[0].h",
    "g[1].h",
    "g[0]h", # dot after ] is not necessary
    "a[1][1]",
    "d",
    "g",
    "g[7]",
    "k",
    "d.z",
    "d[1]",
    "g[z]",
    "[4]",
    "[d]",
    "].].s8[3[",
]:
    print(f"{path}: {find(struct, path)}")

Outputs:
d.e: 4
g[0].h: 6
g[1].h: 8
g[0]h: 6
a[1][1]: 4
d: {'e': 4, 'f': 5}
g: [{'h': 6, 'i': 7}, {'h': 8, 'i': 9}]
g[7]: None
k: None
d.z: None
d[1]: None
g[z]: None
[4]: None
[d]: None
].].s8[3[: None


I've worked out a hacky-way of doing it, taking inspiration from this answer Nested dictionary value from key path. The answer from that post does not handle nested arrays, however, I made a small change to that function to accommodate the use of indexes within a key, e.g. g[0].h
def find(element, json):
    keys = element.split('.')
    rv = json
    for key in keys:
        if "[" not in key:
            rv = rv[key]
        else:
            index_split = key.split("[")
            bracket_split = index_split[-1].split("]")
            index = int(bracket_split[0])
            rv = rv[index_split[0]][index]

    return rv

d = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": {
        "e": 4,
        "f": 5
    },
    "g": [{
        "h": 6,
        "i": 7
    },
    {
        "h": 8,
        "i": 9
    }]
}

print(find("g[0].h", d))
#returns 6


This parses and casts keys from the "keystring", and reduces to the final value. This solution doesn't care at all about your delimiters. It just keeps getting word characters [a-zA-Z0-9_], until it hits something that isn't a word character. This solution also automatically turns integer keys into an int. This means you can't use ints in str format as dictionary keys. ex: {"1":None}. You can do this, though: {1:None}
solution
import functools, operator, re
from typing import Any

def find(src:dict, key:str) -> Any:
    # parse and cast keys
    keys = map(lambda x: (str,int)[x.isdigit()](x), re.findall(r'\w+', key))
    
    # reduce to value
    return functools.reduce(operator.getitem, keys, src)

usage
data = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": {
        "e": 4,
        "f": 5
    },
    "g": [{
        "h": 6,
        "i": 7
    },
    {
        "h": 8,
        "i": 9
    }]
}


print(find(data, 'g[1].h')) #8

# keys just need to be separated by non-word characters
# it doesn't matter which characters or the number of them
print(find(data, 'g 1 h')) #8

